# Error : redifinition; different basic types

Tags: c

I wrote a basic recursive code but an error occurred:

> redifinition; different basic types

Here is the code:

```
int m=1; 
void countDown(int n) 
{ /* count down */ 
    printf("Count down: %d\t", n--); 
    if(n<1) return; /* terminate recursion */ 
    else countUP(n); /* start/continue indirect recursion */ 
} 

void countUP(int n) 
{ 
    printf("up: %d\n", m++); 
    countDown(n); 
    /* indirect recursion */ 
}

void main()
{

    countDown(5);
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In `countDown`, you use the function `countUP` which hasn't been declared so far. According to §3.3.2.2 of [C89](http://flash-gordon.me.uk/ansi.c.txt), when a function is undeclared when used, it is declared *implicitly* as

```
extern int countUP();
```

Later, you actually declare (and implement) `countUP`, but as `void countUP(int n)`, which doesn't match the above signature.

Declare `countUP` by adding

```
void countUP(int n);
```

*before* `countDown`. While you're at it, you should also

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

for `printf`.